# Spring Security 4.1 upgrade - Error 403 Access Denied

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am getting 403 Access Denied Error code on upgrading to Spring Security 4.1.2 and Spring 4.3.2

Spring-Security.xml file

```
    ...
<spring:bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
</spring:bean>

<spring:bean id="authenticatedVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>

<spring:bean id="webExpressionVoter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter" />

<spring:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
      <spring:constructor-arg>
       <spring:list>
            <spring:ref bean="roleVoter"/>
            <spring:ref bean="authenticatedVoter"/>
            <spring:ref bean="webExpressionVoter"/>
        </spring:list>
  </spring:constructor-arg>
</spring:bean>

<security:http access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" auto-config='true' use-expressions="true">

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')" />

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>

    <security:form-login login-page="/login.jsp"
        username-parameter="j_username"
        password-parameter="j_password"
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
        authentication-failure-url="/accessDenied.jsp" />

    <security:logout invalidate-session="true"  delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>

    <security:csrf disabled="true"/>

</security:http>
...
```

I am using Spring Security AuthenticationProvider class for Authentication. authenticate(Authentication authentication) method in the class is executed successfully and returns new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, pwd, authorities).

Error stacktrace:

```
2016-09-02 14:59:21,461 DEBUG [http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1] [org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:66)] - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@52989292, returned: 0
2016-09-02 14:59:21,461 DEBUG [http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1] [org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:66)] - Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@203cc7cd, returned: 0
2016-09-02 14:59:21,461 DEBUG [http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1] [org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:66)] - Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@5e01cc46, returned: -1
2016-09-02 14:59:21,462 DEBUG [http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1] [org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:362)] - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: org.springframework.security.access.event.AuthorizationFailureEvent[source=FilterInvocation: URL: /index.html]
2016-09-02 14:59:21,462 DEBUG [http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1] [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleSpringSecurityException(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:186)] - Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
```

From the error stacktrace, WebExpressionVoter is returning -1.

Comment: Prior to Spring Security 4.1 migration, WebExpressionVoter was not added in AffirmativeBased decision manager. But, in 4.1, it seems mandatory to add the WebExpressionVoter. And, this voter is returning -1.

Comment: Also, why below line from error stacktrace is saying 'not anonymous'?  - Access is denied (user is not anonymous)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is resolved after replacing hasRole with hasAuthority in spring security file.

Answer (score 0):

If we use a `hasAnyRole` , `hasRole` in many places it is not feasible to replace all with `hasAuthority`. This is a really confusing upgrade in Spring. We need to append ROLE_ the role name if we want to use the same role name as Spring 3. For example if you were using APP_ADMIN, Spring 3 will evaluate `hasRole(APP_ADMIN)` as true if the logged in user has role APP_ADMIN. For the same thing to work in Spring 4, you need to change the role to ROLE_APP_ADMIN for `hasRole(APP_ADMIN)` to be true.

This does not make any sense at all apart creating confusion, whatever be the explanation the 'creators' give